# How to compare word length of every item in a comboBox?

Tags: c#, combobox, compare

Hi i'm trying to figure out how to to compare the character length of each individual item in a combobox.
I tried a few things but nothing worked.

```
string longestName = "";
foreach (string possibleDate in comboBox1)
```

But this foreach gives me an error.

```
comboBox1.Text.Length
```

this does give me the length of the item selected, but doesn't compare ALL of them.
I would apreciate your help!

Comment: it should be `comboBox1.Items`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not iterating through the ComboBox's item list.

Try something like this:

```
string longestName = "";
foreach (string possibleDate in comboBox1.Items)
{
    int stringLength = possibleDate.Length;
    if(stringLength > longestName.Length)
        longestName = possibleDate;
}
```

Or you could skip that and use LINQ:

```
var longestName = comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().OrderByDescending(item => item.Length).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
  string longestName = "";
    foreach (string possibleDate in comboBox1.Items){
       if(longestName.Length < possibleDate.Length){
          longestName = possibleDate;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a few factors. Are the items of type `string` or some other class? Are ypu populating your `ComboBox` manually or is it bound to the `DataSource`?

manually populated/of type string

```
        string longestName = "";

        comboBox1.Items.Add("aaa ddd ddd");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("aaa");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("aaa ff");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("aaa x");

        foreach (string possibleDate in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            int stringLength = possibleDate.Length;
            if (stringLength > longestName.Length)
                longestName = possibleDate;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(longestName);
        //or:
        string longest = comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

manually populated/of complex type

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

        comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyClass { MyProperty = "aaa ddd ddd" });
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyClass { MyProperty = "aaa" });
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyClass { MyProperty = "aaa ff" });
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyClass { MyProperty = "aaa x" });

        foreach (MyClass possibleDate in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            int stringLength = possibleDate.MyProperty.Length;
            if (stringLength > longestName.Length)
                longestName = possibleDate.MyProperty;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(longestName);
        //or
        string longest = comboBox1.Items.Cast<MyClass>().OrderByDescending(a => a.MyProperty.Length).FirstOrDefault().MyProperty;
```

if you override `ToString()` method for `MyClass` you can do this:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return MyProperty;
        }
    }

    string longest = comboBox1.Items.Cast<MyClass>().OrderByDescending(a => a.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

...or you can use `GetItemText()` of the `ComboBox`:

```
        foreach (MyClass possibleDate in comboBox1.Items)
        {

            int stringLength = comboBox1.GetItemText(possibleDate).Length;
            if (stringLength > longestName.Length)
                longestName = comboBox1.GetItemText(possibleDate);
        }
```

if your `ComboBox` is bound, you don't have to override `ToString()` method to use `GetItemText()`, and this way is's independent of the type of item:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public decimal MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

         BindingList<MyClass> source = new BindingList<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass { MyProperty = 1.0001m},
            new MyClass { MyProperty = 100001.5555m},
            new MyClass { MyProperty = 4m},
            new MyClass { MyProperty = 300.5m }
        };

        comboBox1.DataSource = source;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "MyProperty";
        foreach (object possibleDate in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            int stringLength = comboBox1.GetItemText(possibleDate).Length;
            if (stringLength > longestName.Length)
                longestName = comboBox1.GetItemText(possibleDate);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(longestName);
        //or
        string longest = comboBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Select(a => comboBox1.GetItemText(a)).OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```